# Passing parameters to a wrapper in python through variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameter-passing, wrapper, biopython

Is it possible to send parameters through a variable to wrapper in python? The wrapper I am using works properly when parameters are provided directly. For example:

```
ClustalOmegaCommandline(infile='abc.fasta', auto=True, verbose=True, force=True)
```

works fine. But passing parameters through a variable, for example,

```
param = "infile='abc.fasta', auto=True, verbose=True, force=True"
ClustalOmegaCommandline(param)
```

results in 'Non-zero return code as param is not recognized as an internal or external command'.

Wrapper recognizes param only as a string but cannot recognize them as parameters. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with wrapper here, but can't you use a `dict` as your variable, and use dict expansion? Thus: `param = {'infile': 'abc.fast', 'auto': True, 'verbose': True, 'force': True}; ClustalOmegaCommandline(**param)`.

Comment: Take a look at this - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters/26365795#26365795)  It's a way to send and arbitrary number of arguments to a function.  Is this the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Using dictionary instead of variable solves the problem! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Evert, It's been a while but if you would post yours as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
param = {'infile' : 'abc.fasta', 'auto' : True , 'verbose' : True, 'force' : True}
ClustalOmegaCommandline(**param)
```